# Intellij test run history

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, intellij-idea, junit

What I miss the most in IntelliJ compared to Eclipse is the test run history window. Does anything like this exist in IntelliJ? I didn't find it anywhere so far and have looked a few times at least.

In our project we have ~500 integration test cases which take like 5 minutes to run from IDE. Often I have a situation where for e.g. 5 tests fail in 2-3 different classes. I fix something, that should remove failures from first test suite, rerun it to see if it helped and I must rerun all 500 tests to see which classes contained failures earlier. That is really painful. In eclipse I would just lookup those in test history, repair them also and finally run all 500 to check if nothing new camed up.

Is there a plugin out there or do I miss something obvious?

I use IntelliJ 13.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can right-click a tab with test results and select the "Pin Tab" option from the context menu. Then further test executions will not overwrite this tab, and you can still refer to it to see which other tests you need to fix.

Comment: FYI, the button you want looks like a physical pushpin. It's not related to "Pinned Mode" which you would see if you click on the tab in the tab bar in e.g. Run or Debug tabs on the bottom.

Answer (score 11):

On the current version of Intellij (2016), you have now a way to reimport older test Result. On the runner tab, click on the button "Import test Results", and select the one you want
[image: Tests Tab Buttons bar screenshot]

EDIT : In the latest version, you have a "Recent Tests" action which allow you to see older test result without a need to open the rest windows. Shortcut **Ctrl+Shift+Semicolon**

Comment: "Import test Results" is the exact feature I was looking for but was apparently not available at the time of writing this question.

Answer (score 2):

Not relevant for Idea 13, but in 2021 this functionality is present in Idea.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-and-exploring-test-results.html#view-previous

Answer (score 1):

You can also click the "Test History" button to see the old tests result.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, given that you are using the IntelliJ test runner (rather than running the tests via maven), you can use the *Rerun Failed Tests* function.

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/rerunning-tests.html

Edit: based on your comment, can I suggest you run the single test you are working on in "debug" mode, this won't erase the history of your compelte test suite, and you can do that in in combination with the *Rerun Failed Tests* as needed.

Comment: I know that functionality and it is not exactly the same as run history. When I and make a small correction in one test I usually don't run all test that failed - only the one I changed. This way I lose the history and 'rerun failed tests' will run only the single one or none if I've fixed it.

Comment: Ok, then why not run individual tests in debug mode, and use "rerun failed tests" as needed until all tests are green (please see my edit).

Comment: Looks like there is no direct answer to this which in my opinion is a great shame for such a fantastic IDE. Thanks for your suggestions and help.